# HLS && .m3u8in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, m3u8, avkit

I am trying to get a .m3u8 video stream to play within my app. I am programming in Swift for iOS 9 and 10.

Here is what I got so far:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import DynamicBlurView

class VideoPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    var urlString: String!
    let blurView = DynamicBlurView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        streamVideo()
    }

    func streamVideo() {
        blurView.frame = view.frame
        UIView.showProgressView(on: view, blurView: blurView)

        let url = URL(string: urlString!)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

        UIView.hideProgressView(on: view, blurView: blurView)
        player?.play()
    }
}
```

This should be simple, but I am getting errors and crashes all over the place.

This is the error I am getting:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could
>   not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could
>   not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x7b5b6810 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12782 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12782)}

Please help me!

EDIT:

Tried this suggestion with no luck. the app still crashes. The crash brings me to the AppDelegate if that info helps anyone.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import DynamicBlurView

class VideoPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    var urlString: String!
    let blurView = DynamicBlurView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        streamVideo()
    }

    func streamVideo() {
        blurView.frame = view.frame
        UIView.showProgressView(on: view, blurView: blurView)

        let sampleURL = "https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8"

        guard let url = URL(string: sampleURL) else { return }
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player?.play()

        UIView.hideProgressView(on: view, blurView: blurView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your URL provides a valid HLS source.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class myAVPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // custom HLS
        // http://localhost:3000/assets/videos/iframe_index.m3u8
        // apple HLS example
        // https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8") else { return }
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player?.play()
    }
}
```

Also, remember to set the **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** key to **YES** under **NSAppTransportSecurity** dictionary in your **Info.plist**.